# How to translate a rotating script based on mouse dragging to use touch input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script I'm using inside the Editor to rotate a sprite and I want to translate this script to use Touch Input instead of the mouse.

I have the following script I'm using to rotate a sprite in my game based on my mouse dragging. I don't really have experience with touch input so what I tried was something I've seen in some other code using Touch Inputs.
Basically, I changed the if statements:
From

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            deltaRotation = 0f;
            previousRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        }
```

to:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                deltaRotation = 0f;
                previousRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
            }
        }
```

This is my code right now, the one I'm using to rotate my sprite around with my mouse:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            deltaRotation = 0f;
            previousRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            currentRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
            deltaRotation = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentRotation, previousRotation);
            if (Mathf.Abs(deltaRotation) > deltaLimit)
            {
                deltaRotation = deltaLimit * Mathf.Sign(deltaRotation);
            }
            previousRotation = currentRotation;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime, deltaRotation);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime, deltaRotation);
            deltaRotation = Mathf.Lerp(deltaRotation, 0, deltaReduce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code? Is it not compiling? Does it never rotate? You haven't described the problem here at all.

Comment: @Ruzihm The scripts works perfectly well, I just want to make it work for mobile devices, to rotate the sprite with your finger. Right now it only works on my computer, as I'm using my mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if/else` statement uses more equivalent conditions than just `TouchPhase.Moved`.

It looks like the equivalent `TouchPhases` are as folllows.

`TouchPhase.Began` in place of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`

`TouchPhase.Moved` in place of `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`

`TouchPhase.Ended` in place of the final `else`

PS: Gave same answer on UnityAnswers

So, it could look like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            deltaRotation = 0f;
            previousRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            currentRotation = angleBetweenPoints(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
            deltaRotation = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentRotation, previousRotation);
            if (Mathf.Abs(deltaRotation) > deltaLimit)
            {
                deltaRotation = deltaLimit * Mathf.Sign(deltaRotation);
            }
            previousRotation = currentRotation;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime, deltaRotation);
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime, deltaRotation);
            deltaRotation = Mathf.Lerp(deltaRotation, 0, deltaReduce * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, really appreciate you helping me. So, following your advice, my Update function should now look something like this?
```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (touch.TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if(touch.TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: @RaduMitroi I went ahead and added code that uses akaBase's recommendation.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks, thought pointing in the right direction would have been enough.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, guys. Thank you!